# Orthonormal basis of a subspace of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, and $\{e_n\}$ an orthonormal basis for $H$. Is $\{pe_i\}$ an orthogonal basis for $K$, if $K$ is a closed subspace of $H$, and $p:H\to K$ is an orthogonal projection?

I know for every $\xi\in K$, $$\sum c_ie_i =\xi=p\xi=\sum c_ipe_i$$where $\{c_i\}\in \ell^2$.
But what about Perpendicular? Is $\langle pe_i,pe_j\rangle = 0$?

Comment: If $H$ is finite-dimensional and $K$ is strictly smaller dimensional, then obviously $\{ p e_i \}$ is not going to be linearly independent (and therefore they can't be mutually orthogonal either assuming they're all nonzero).

Comment: @DanielSchepler , Right. What's your suggestion to extract a basis for $K$ of $\{e_i\}$?

Comment: There's always Gram-Schmidt...

Comment: @NateEldredge Hi. In general, isn't it true that the restriction of any orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for $H$ to a closed subspace $S$ (that is, the set $\{e_j: e_j \in S\}$) an orthonormal basis for $S$?

Comment: @asrxiiviii: No.  In fact, the set $\{e_j : e_j \in S\}$ may very well be empty.  Consider $H = \mathbb{R}^2$, the usual orthonormal basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$, and the subspace $S$ spanned by $e_1 + e_2$.